# How to open ripgrep search in new tab

Tags: ripgrep

I'm able to search open a file in the current tab, but not able to open in a new tab.

I was watching this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fP_ckZ30gbs&feature=youtu.be&t=1365), but I'm unable to open a file in tabs or splits. When I try <kbd>ctrl-t</kbd> I get this error
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check help file for the quickfix you will find that it has `<CR>` to
open in existing window and `<C-w><CR>` to open in a split window. There is
also a mapping to move a split to a new tab `<C-w>T` -- so we have some pieces
to work with.

Simple mapping `:nnoremap <C-t> <C-w><CR><C-w>T` does the job.

Pressing `<C-t>` would:

1. create new split window (`<C-w><CR>`)
2. move this split window to a new tab (`<C-w>T`)

But this `<C-t>` is now available everywhere which doesn't make sense -- you
should create this mapping only for a quickfix window:

```
augroup quickfix_tab | au!
    au filetype qf nnoremap <buffer> <C-t> <C-w><CR><C-w>T
augroup END
```

[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm new to vim . I just want <C-t> to open the highlighted line in new tab. But that is not happening for me.

Comment: @NikhilWagh this answer is about it.

Comment: I copied your `augroup` into my `vimrc` and it worked thanks.

Comment: An ftplugin would work as well.